Zoom ZRC SDK need some advise
I have a project(web application - vue.js and node.js) right now that requires a zoom room implementation i saw zoom room api but the project owner insist that I follow this https://developers.zoom.us/docs/zoom-rooms/zoom-rooms-controller/integrate-sdk-app/ after I read the docs it seems its for a C++ i just need like a advise if im right that this is not applicable on the project. I will be needing a reply tomorrow because the owner really insist that this is the only way
I already tried research but to be honest cant really understand the docs
